# Changing colors in the modern UI seems impossible

Tags: interface, acumatica

We have a client with many companies and they want each company to have their own user interface color.  Makes sense.  But when I go to add a new user interface color, before I do anything other than change the name of the profile, the menu screen appears completely messed up and will not allow a selection on the screen.  The classic UI works fine.  But of course the customer wants the new UI.  Anyone else experience this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Most of Acumatica can still be customized the same way as explained in the Classic UI guides.

https://adn.acumatica.com/blog/acumatica-customization-theming-white-labeling/
http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2015/12/doing-personalized-demo.html

Here is a quick example where I changed the background color to brown by using my "Brown" theme.

[image]

As you can see, I also managed to change the Modern UI top bar color to orange. To do this, you need to create an extra css file in your Website\Content folder. Just follow the filename convention which is Site{Theme}.css

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I dont find that it works tho.  Whenever I change the color in the file, it continues to mess up the Modern UI.  And then it wont other companies use the Modern UI.  But thanks.

Comment: I notice in the indigo color scheme it does not ever use the same color in the new UI.  Would you happen to know what the color code used in the Modern UI is?  At least I could try to change it that way.  I also see that using the Content file doesnt populate the site preferences screen.